# Segmentation Fault using strtok() in C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strtok

I get segmentation fault with the following code using `strtok`. Am I using `strtok` correctly?

```
int main()
{
    dummy("90:90");
    return 0;
}
int dummy(char *str)
{
    char *mm, *hh;
    int len = strlen(str), result;

    if (len <= 0 || len > 5)
    {
            return 0;
    }

    hh = strtok(str, ":");

    while(hh){
        printf("%s", hh);
        hh = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can not use `strtok()` with a constant string. And that what you did in your code.

Because the `strtok()` edit the string and the constant strings are a read only strings.

To fix your problem, Duplicate your string in a dynamic allocated memory (read-write memory) in this way:

```
int dummy(char *str)
{
    char *mm, *hh;
    int len = strlen(str), result;

    if (len <= 0 || len > 5)
    {
            return 0;
    }

    char *buf = strdup(str); // Modif here


    hh = strtok(buf, ":"); // Modif here

    while(hh){
        printf("%s", hh);
        hh = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }

    free(buf); // Modif here

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`strtok` modified the content of its argument, so you can't pass a string literal. Change it to:

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "90:90";
    dummy(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When function `strtok` is called with the first argument being a string which is not `NULL`, it changes the contents of that string, so that in the following calls (with `NULL`) it will be able to fetch the next token.

You, however, are passing a constant string which resides in the (read-only) code-section of your program. So during run-time, the CPU attempts to write into a read-only memory section, leading to an illegal memory access.

In short, you need to declare the string as a local array in the stack of function `main`:

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "90:90";
    dummy(str);
    return 0;
}
```